# how to convert JSON string to object in JAVA android

Tags: java, android

How do I to convert a JSON string to object in Java Android  so that I can access "name2"

thanks

```
// this is how my json looks {"name1":"a","name2":"b","name3":"c","name4":"d"}

String mytext = GetMyJSON();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mytext);

Strin N1  = obj.name1;
```

Comment: @nr4bt sugersts the legal way to map your json to object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do Something like this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mytext);

if(obj!=null)
{
  Strin N1  = obj.getString("name1");
  Strin N2  = obj.getString("name2");
  Strin N3  = obj.getString("name3");
  Strin N4  = obj.getString("name4");
}
```

Comment: And where is the object to which is converted the JSON?

Answer (score 7):

If a library is ok for you, GSON would help about it. it converts JSON to object, so you can reach them such as yourclassinst.name

[refer this one](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: I'd recommend Jackson over GSON, it's faster. http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload