# Android, Iterate over JSON-fied dictionary

Tags: android, json

I have the following string, which was created using javascript JSON. (It's passed from a Webview to the native code using JavascriptInterface.)

```
{"var1":1,"var2":8}
```

How do I convert that into an object and then iterate over the key/value pairs? The names of the keys are NOT known in advance.

I have seen this [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java) and this [Converting json string to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079505/converting-json-string-to-java-object) and this [how to convert JSON string to object in JAVA android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350280/how-to-convert-json-string-to-object-in-java-android).

None of those seem to fit with my example, which is a dictionary with unknown key names. At least, it's certainly not clear to me which of the 15+ answers is relevant for my case.

Comment: The first choice you need to make is which json library you're going to use. Gson, json.org, etc. Do you have one in mind / do you care?

Comment: Nope, I don't care. I just need to iterate over the values in some way!

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what type the _values_ will be? Are they always `int`? Or do you need to be able to handle any type?

Comment: They will always be strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.json` library comes "for free" with Android, so I'd go with that. Usage when you don't know the keys ahead of time could be something like this:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(/* your json String here */);
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        String value = jsonObject.getString(key);

        // do whatever you want with key/value
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    // thrown when:
    // - the json string is malformed (can't be parsed)
    // - there's no value for a requested key
    // - the value for the requested key can't be coerced to String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by converting the getting the json length like this:-
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

```
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
    //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
     JSONObject heroObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);
     String aka=heroObject.getString("your key here");
}
```

Comment: Then how do I get the key/value pairs once I have that object?

Comment: you can store them in a String like this:- String aka=heroObject.getString("your key here");

Comment: I don't know the names of the keys in advance. I need to iterate over the object and extract all the keys and values.

Comment: ok so you can firstly store the length of the JSON object and declare an public empty string  like String s=""; then do like this: -          for(int i=0;i<lengthOFJSON;i++){       s=s+heroObject.getJSONObject(i);   }